# Get true or false if Records present table having two foreign Key along with both table record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I do not have much experience in SQL. trying to work out query as below:
i have three table A,B and C. table C have foreign key from table A and table B.

```
table A => Employee details, 
table B => Training Details,
table C => save which Employee has completed which training.
```

so need basically fetch Employee Name(All), Training Name(All), True if Emp. completed particular Training or else false.

```
select distinct innerEmp.EmployeeID, innerEmp.FirstName + ' ' + innerEmp.LastName as EmpName,
innerTrain.TrainingID, innerTrain.TrainingName
from tblEmployee innerEmp, tblTraining innerTrain
```

Above giving me first two column. but table `tblEmployeeTraining (table C)` how to get third column (True if Emp. completed particular Training or else false).

Example

```
create table student(
snum numeric(9,0) primary key,
sname varchar(30),
major varchar(25),
standing varchar(2),
age numeric(3,0)
);
create table class(
name varchar(40) primary key,
meets_at varchar(20),
room varchar(10),
fid numeric(9,0),
);
create table enrolled(
snum numeric(9,0),
cname varchar(40),
primary key(snum,cname),
foreign key (snum) references
student(snum),
foreign key (cname) references
class(name)
);
```

Result i expect below:
[image]

Please Help

Comment: Start by switching from comma joins to explicit joins.

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) Most likely you can achieve what you want with a `LEFT JOIN`; which is impossible to do with that 1980's implicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: left join no..i tried it will only give name of employee completed training ....as i could simply join all three tables..but thats not what is requirement...even if employee not completed any training it should fetch records

Comment: i updated my question with example....Can any one check how i can fetch result